# zoom in/out and scroll panning image on blackberry using javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, blackberry, zooming

I'm programming on web to build the application in blackberry. Now I want to make my image in the web can be zoom in or out and after the user can scroll in up/down/left/right with the scroll bar or panning bar like google maps did.

There are the plugin in jquery/javascript to do this? I didn't found any plugin/library to do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you can use jQuery pan zoom plugin to zoom the image on web. Try this site http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/pan-zoom/.

**Update** : You can use Smooth Zoom Pan plugin that have full feature to zoom image but you must buy this plugin.
See the demo : http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142 .